# How to root htc desire 326g dual?

Tags: rooting, htc-desire, htc

I have HTC desire 326g dual SIM. It regularly revert back it setting. Like when installed apex launcher and selected always for using it but it always asks for launcher on restart. And it runs on kit Kat. I think now kit Kat is old so I want to replace the os too. I've tried to root it with kingo one click root apk as well as many more methods described in different sites. So any guide line.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you've gotta unlock the bootloader on the HTC dev (you've gotta sign up first it's free) and you need to use the fastboot oem unlock command if they still support that model of phone. but the sad news is that phone is not a very well know phone at all so there is not root at the moment. so you stuck on a non rooted phone. theres no recovery like cwm or trwp.